# Directory Permission

Tags: permissions, redhat-enterprise-linux

My server is running redhat and has two users A and B,

User A ownes /dirA

Now I have created /dirA/dirB and did

chown -R B:B /dirA/dirB/

when I su B and cd /dirA/dirB/ it workes fine.
But when I directly login from user B and cd to above mentioned directory, I get "Permission Denied"

Answer (score 0):

> su

and

> su -

will produce much different results.  su - will read in the environment of the new user replacing the prior environment.  su will merge them.

check your identity with the

```
id
```

command and you may discover why you have permissions.  It could be that you retained a group membership that allows you access.

Comment: Problem is not why user B can access, it's why user B cannot access when B has ownership of the directory

Comment: A user may belong to several groups.  If user B does not have identical group memberships, as identified by the id command, then look for a directory in the path that impedes the user.  A folder in the path that does not have read and or execute (search) permissions can impede a user.  *nix permissions are very straightforward.  When logged in as the user with the defect, start at / and cd folder by folder and do an ls.  This may help find the folder that is giving this user a problem.  Then look at the id's in relation to the folder owner/group and check /etc/group.